# CET and CEST conversion to UTC

Tags: python, pandas

I have code to convert the Europe/Brussels time to UTC. Will this code take care of both CET and CEST conversions ? i.e. does it handle day light savings conversion as well to UTC ? If not, can some one suggest how to handle it ?

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + " " + df['time']).dt.tz_localize('Europe/Brussels').\
     dt.tz_convert('UTC').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Below data is available in Netherlands time. So, it is converted into UTC.

```
1/17/2018   1   0:00
1/17/2018   2   0:01
1/17/2018   3   0:02
1/17/2018   4   0:03
1/17/2018   5   0:04
1/17/2018   6   0:05
1/17/2018   7   0:06
1/17/2018   8   0:07
```

Comment: Can you add some data samples?

Comment: Sure, I changed the original question details.

Comment: Does your original data file handle the summertime correctly? Because I usually can't use your (correct) line, as it will throw an "AmbiguousTimeError" or "NonExistentTimeError", as almost no datafile I come across handles this properly. Below an answer for this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it handles DST natively. Check this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(['2017-08-30 12:00:00', '2017-12-30 12:00:00'])})
df['date'].dt.tz_localize('Europe/Brussels').dt.tz_convert('UTC').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I picked one date with DST, i.e. UTC+1+1 and the other is only UTC+1 (where +1 is for Brussels). The output shows, that first date is converted as minus 2 hours, while the second date is minus 1 hour.

```
0    2017-08-30 10:00:00
1    2017-12-30 11:00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, sorry if I use this as a sort of gist for future own reference :). BUT, while the answer of @Michal Ficek is technically correct, it usually never works for me in real life with data files I come across. When I get a time series file with a local time column, like yours, in 90% of times I'll get an exception with that line. So I'd check what is going on around the transitions from and to summertime.

Ideally (well at least in absence of explicit offset information) you would want to see something like this:

```
#test_good.csv
local_time,value
...
2017-03-26 00:00,2016
2017-03-26 01:00,2017
2017-03-26 03:00,2018
2017-03-26 04:00,2019
...
2017-10-29 01:00,7224
2017-10-29 02:00,7225
2017-10-29 02:00,7226
2017-10-29 03:00,7227
...
```

But most often you see this:

```
# test_bad.csv
local_time,value
...
2017-03-26 00:00,2016
2017-03-26 01:00,2017
2017-03-26 02:00,2018   # should not exist, so people made up number?
2017-03-26 03:00,2018
2017-03-26 04:00,2019
...
2017-10-29 00:00,7223
2017-10-29 01:00,7224   # so here is a value missing now
2017-10-29 02:00,7226
2017-10-29 03:00,7227
...
```

So if you use your line as is on test_good.csv, you'll get an AmbiguousTimeError, but this is can easily be handled with the `ambiguous="infer"` flag:

```
df_good['utc_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_good["local_time"]).dt.tz_localize('CET', ambiguous="infer").dt.tz_convert('UTC').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Then everything works perfectly fine.

But not for test_bad.csv: No flag results in `NonExistentTimeError` as there is a time stamp that shouldn't exist. So try `ambiguous="infer"` and you get an `AmbiguousTimeError`, as it doesn't know how to handle the non-reapeated time. This could be fixed with `ambiguous="NaT"`, which again throws `NonExistentTimeError`. Yey, full circle.

So far I fixed that a few times via hand (always googling the respective country's summer time transition dates). So I used your question this morning to come up with this (though hacky) function:

```
def add_utc_from_localtime(df, local_time_column='local_time', values=['value']):
    try: # here everything is as expected
        df['utc_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df[local_time_column])
                                .dt.tz_localize('CET', ambiguous="infer")
                                .dt.tz_convert('UTC').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    except AmbiguousTimeError as e: # okay, so he excepts one line to be there twice
        d = re.findall(r'from (.+?) as', str(e))[0] # get the date from error message
        df.loc[df.index[-1] + 1,:] = [d, np.NaN] # add a line with this date at the end
        df = df.sort_values(local_time_column) # sort according to date column
        df[values] = df[values].interpolate() # make up some new value by interpolating
        try:
            df['utc_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df[local_time_column])
                                .dt.tz_localize('CET', ambiguous="infer")
                                .dt.tz_convert('UTC').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')        
        except NonExistentTimeError as e2: # okay, now the problem is one date is there twice
            df = df.drop(df[df.local_time == str(e2)].index) # drop it based on error message
            df['utc_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df[local_time_column])
                                .dt.tz_localize('CET', ambiguous="infer")
                                .dt.tz_convert('UTC').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return df
```

Of course this may break with an pandas update, as it relies on the error message format. But better than always going through some years of data manually.

Below a complete example with test data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pytz.exceptions import AmbiguousTimeError, NonExistentTimeError
import re

#generate good data
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(start="1.1.2017",end="01.01.2018",freq="H",closed="left", tz="CET")
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.arange(0.0,float(len(idx))),index=idx)
df.to_csv("test_good.csv",date_format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",header=["value"],index_label="local_time")

df_good = pd.read_csv("test_good.csv", header=0)
# results in AmbiguousTimeError
#df_good['utc_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_good["local_time"]).dt.tz_localize('CET').dt.tz_convert('UTC').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# works
df_good['utc_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_good["local_time"]).dt.tz_localize('CET', ambiguous="infer").dt.tz_convert('UTC').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# works
df_good = add_utc_from_localtime(df_good)

#generate bad handled data
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(start="1.1.2017",end="01.01.2018",freq="H",closed="left")
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.arange(0.0,float(len(idx))),index=idx)
df["2017-03-26 03:00":"2017-10-29 01:00"] -= 1 # simulate bad handling
df.to_csv("test_bad.csv",date_format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",header=["value"],index_label="local_time")

df_bad = pd.read_csv("test_bad.csv", header=0)
# results in NonExistentTimeError
#df_bad['utc_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_bad["local_time"]).dt.tz_localize('CET').dt.tz_convert('UTC').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# results in NonExistentTimeError
#df_bad['utc_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_bad["local_time"]).dt.tz_localize('CET', ambiguous="infer").dt.tz_convert('UTC').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# works
df_bad = add_utc_from_localtime(df_bad)
```

Of course, if I missed some other more elegant way, I'll be happy to learn also (maybe I'll make it another question then).

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem as described in [Marcus V's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48325058/6245540) with real world datasets. Mine had one value at 3am in March, raising `InconsistentTimeError`, and only one value at 2am in October, raising `AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from %r, try using the 'ambiguous' argument` without `ambiguous='infer'` and `ValueError: Cannot infer offset with only one time.` with it.

Here is the method I came up with to solve the problem with this kind of dataset, if it can help anyone:

```
def cet_to_utc(df, col_name):
   # Convert dataframe CET/CEST datetimes column to UTC datetimes
   # Example call: cet_to_utc(dataframe, 'Datetime')
   #
   # --- Arguments description --
   # You need to provide as first argument the dataframe you want to modify,
   # and as second argument the column you want to modify.
   idx_name = df.index.name
   df = df.reset_index()
   idx = 0
   while idx != df.index[-1] + 1:
       try:
           df.loc[idx, 'temp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[idx, col_name]).tz_localize('CET').tz_convert('UTC')
           idx += 1
       except:

       # AmbiguousTimeError
       if df.loc[idx, col_name].month == 10:
          # Duplicate the single value we had at 2 am
          df = df.iloc[:idx, ].append(df.iloc[idx]).append(df.iloc[idx:, ]).reset_index(drop=True)
          # Convert both rows to UTC
          df.loc[idx, 'temp'] = pd.to_datetime(
                 pd.to_datetime(df.loc[idx, col_name]) - pd.Timedelta(hours=2)).tz_localize('UTC')
          df.loc[idx + 1, 'temp'] = pd.to_datetime(
                 pd.to_datetime(df.loc[idx, col_name]) - pd.Timedelta(hours=1)).tz_localize('UTC')
          idx += 2

       # InconsistentTimeError
       else:
          # Delete the 3 am row
          df.drop(idx, inplace=True)
          df = df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

   df[col_name] = df['temp']
   df = df.drop(labels='temp', axis=1)
   if idx_name:
      df = df.set_index(idx_name)
      df.index.name = idx_name
   else:
      df = df.set_index('index')
      df.index.name = None
   return df
```